# wsdl extension to add new attribute

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am doing project related to WSDL, and I wanto to add new attribute to my WSDL file.
Main structure of WSDL is:

```
<definitions>

<types>
  data type definitions........
</types>

<message>
  definition of the data being communicated....
</message>

<portType>
  set of operations......
</portType>

<binding>
  protocol and data format specification....
</binding>

</definitions>
```

What I want to do is to add Quality of Service (QoS) attribute to the wsdl, so the new structure is become like this:

```
<definitions>

<types>
  data type definitions........
</types>

<message>
  definition of the data being communicated....
</message>

<portType>
  set of operations......
</portType>

<binding>
  protocol and data format specification....
</binding>
<QoS>
Qos criteria.....
</QoS>
</definitions>
```

For example this attribute will be added to the wsdl:

```
  <Reliability Qualification="threshold-best-effort" Offered="true">
        <TimeToFailure value= 500000000 unit="sec" source="measured"
        type=”mean” direction=”increasing />
 </Reliability>
```

The result should be like this, the `<Reliability>` attribute will be inserted into `<service>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://sample" xmlns:qwsdl="http://example.com/stockquote/schemas"  xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://sample" xmlns:intf="http://sample" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->
<wsdl:import namespace = "http://localhost:8080/WSDLExtention/wsdl/stockquote.xsd" location="http://localhost:8080/WSDLExtention/wsdl/stockquote.xsd"/>
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://sample" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <element name="myCalculation">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="decimal" type="xsd:string"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <element name="myCalculationResponse">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="myCalculationReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>

  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>

   <wsdl:message name="myCalculationResponse">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:myCalculationResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="myCalculationRequest">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:myCalculation" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:portType name="Calculation">

      <wsdl:operation name="myCalculation">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:myCalculationRequest" name="myCalculationRequest">

       </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:myCalculationResponse" name="myCalculationResponse">

       </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:portType>

   <wsdl:binding name="CalculationSoapBinding" type="impl:Calculation">

      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

      <wsdl:operation name="myCalculation">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="myCalculationRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="myCalculationResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:binding>

   <wsdl:service name="CalculationService">

      <wsdl:port binding="impl:CalculationSoapBinding" name="Calculation">

         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/Action1/services/Calculation"/>
      </wsdl:port>

   <Reliability Qualification="threshold-best-effort" Offered="true">
    <TimeToFailure value= 500000000 unit="sec" source="measured"
    type=”mean” direction=”increasing />
    </Reliability>
   </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions
```

I try to add new schema to the wsdl,but it always fail. Is it possible to do it? Any idea how to add this new attribute to WSDL file?

Comment: What is the attribuate ? and what failure do you have ?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you tried and what exception your facing ?

Answer (score 0):

WSDL has a standard [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl), you can not customize it like this.

Define as per this schema based on your binding.

http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#A4.2

Apperently, you can do it using [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#A4.1) schema ([Ext](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#A3))

```
<element name="service" type="wsdl:serviceType"/>
   <complexType name="serviceType">
      <complexContent>
   <extension base="wsdl:documented">
   <sequence>
   <element ref="wsdl:port" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0"/>
  </sequence>
      <attribute name="name" type="NCName" use="required"/>
   </extension>
  </complexContent>
  </complexType>
```

But I never tried this, don't have any sample.

Comment: thank you for your reply, is it possible to me to insert that attribute inside `<service>` , because I saw in this journal it is possible, but I am not really sure how to do it (http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~sutambe/files/Telcordia/Internship/Model-Driven/Model-driven%20WSDL%20Extension%20for%20Describing%20the%20QoS.pdf) .